# How do I buy from the Software Center with a foreign currency?

Tags: software-center, paid-applications

I wonder if there is a way to buy games in the Ubuntu Software Center using the Philippine peso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Software Center supports **Paypal** payments, which should be available in the Philippines and a number of other countries. But I don't know if Paypal will let you pay one-time with a local credit card, or if they will want you to become a member first (it's free to get an account though).

[image]

Source: [omgubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/paypal-payments-now-supported-in-the-ubuntu-software-centre)

Comment: thanks, but I don't use credit cards any more, using credit cards are to complicated here in the Philippines. Banking here are also too complicated. But I will try with the "Smart Money" from our local network called "Smart" if they can provide for this kind of money transfer.

Comment: Is there any application that can convert peso to dollar?, we used to pay using load from broadband.